# can't install the ADT Plugin

Tags: adt

RT.
   It can't connect to https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ or http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

And I open the web site by browser,it returns 404 not found.

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to connect? Those URLS are meant to be pasted in to the Eclipse "Install" window.

To get there click: Help>Install New Software

Then, click the "Add" button and paste the URL in where it says "Location".  Name it ADT (or anything you want) and click "OK".

That should start the install.